Getting different ip addresses for the same hostname
Why do I get different ip addresses for (what seems like) the same host, when resolving a CNAME and its corresponding A records?
❯ host www.github.com
www.github.com is an alias for github.com.
** github.com has address 100.87.99.25 **
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
❯ host github.com
** github.com has address 100.92.53.4 **
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.

tested with both: host, dig commands.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoDNS

Because the name resolves to multiple IP's.
That's perfectly normal and reasonable, and you have to expect it. There's no requirement that a name resolve only to one IP, nor that it needs to be consistent even over short time frames.
